# Load random profile on index page, jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

The current site for which I'm re-designing and developing is http://www.gdi-brighton.co.uk/. Most of the changes are cosmetic, and I've stripped the nav down to 3 links: GDI-Brighton (home page), Profiles and News. The site uses a custom CMS built in PHP from a previous student.

When visiting the home page I'd like for a random student profile page to load. There is an id and name_url for each student, which you can see when clicking on one of the thumbnails for a student on the current site.

I'm familiar with `Math.floor(Math.random())` but have no idea where to start concerning this.

Please let me know if you need any more information. Thanks for your help.

Ryan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a relational database and the ids of the student entities are following a **sequence** (e.g. increasing by 1 etc.), then you can get the current sequence number with a single simple query to your database (you can google for `nextval()` of a sequence on the web). Assign this number to a variable and use it as an upper limit when you are generating a random student id. To handle the cases where the generated random number doesn't correspond a valid student id, (i.e. some of the students might have been deleted from the database.), you can just use a while loop that contains the random id generation code but exists on a valid id generation. After that, just query the database with this valid random id and fetch the url of the profile of the corresponding student.

Comment: Ok, this seems clear enough, find the uppermost id number using `nextval()`, set it as a variable, check that it's valid and pull the url. I've asked google, and can only seem to find queries using sql and oracle. Is there a way I can probe the database using jquery to find the sequence number?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the wait. I had to move onto other work, and I realised that this would require some php beyond my knowledge (which is nil), so I've had to find another student to help. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in your PHP. Here is the concept (not actual working code):

```
$result = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT MIN(id), MAX(id) FROM table"));
$min = $result[0]; $max = $result[1];
$id_to_retrieve = rand($min, $max);
$random_student = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = {$id_to_retrieve} LIMIT 1");
```

Note that this does not check whether the record with that ID exists in the last query. If it doesn't exist you can get another random ID or get the closest ID that does exist.

After all this is done you output the random student card and retrieve the result with jQuery (with load() or something--you don't need to pass any variables to PHP for this).

Answer (score 0):

You can pick a random url on the client-side, too with this code:

```
var url = $('li.illustration:eq('
            + Math.floor($('li.illustration').length * Math.random())
            +')>a').attr('href')
```

But it feels too hackish and the server seems the best place to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this??

```
var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
if (randomnumber == 0) { DisplayProfile(0); }
if (randomnumber == 1) { DisplayProfile(1); }
if (randomnumber == 2) { DisplayProfile(2); }
```

`DisplayProfile` would contain your JQuery code that would organise your page to display the right info based on the information passed (in my example 0, 1 or 2)